# How to get value of next key and value of previous key in an array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have this array:

```
 $arr = array(1, 2, 5, 7);
```

And the current value of the entry is `5`, how do I get the previous value of `2` and next value `7`?

It works if I use the following code:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $check){ 
    if($check == $this->item->id){
        $next = $result[$i+1];
        $prev = $result[$i-1];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I thought at first that the `$arr[$i + 1]` will give me 6

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`next();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) and [`prev();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php)

Like this:

```
current($arr); //Use current to see the current element of your array! So in your example 5
next($arr);    //6
prev($arr);    //5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the array pointer with [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) and [`prev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're also asking why `$arr[$i + 1]` and `$arr[$i - 1]` return the next and previous elements, rather than adding or subtracting from the value of the array element referenced by the index equal to **$i**.

Keep in mind that the brackets enclose the array index. If you have an expression within the brackets, the result of the expression is the index; there's no reason why if the expression contains a variable, then that variable alone would be treated as the index and any other operations would be applied after retrieving the value of the array element.

So, if **$i** is 2, then `$arr[$i + 1]` gives you the value of the element whose *index* is equal to `$i + 1`, i.e. the element with index 3, which is `7`. `$arr[$i] + 1` would give you `6` (retrieves the element whose index is equal to `$i`, and adds 1 to its value).